# databinding in WPF using a base class for field creation in various forms

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I had my application working with the fields being created in a class where each field was generated separately in the usual fashion

```
public class RequestProfileObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     private string strPassword;
     public string Pwd
     { 
         get { return strPassword; }
         set 
         { 
             strPassword = value; 
             // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated 
             OnPropertyChanged("Pwd"); 
         } 
     }

     //Plus other code to load the data into the field and the OnPropertyChanged
     //method 
}
```

then I saw I needed to be able to keep track of changes and came up with a mechanism for that and some other features that I needed.  Needless to say a lot of repeated code which caused me to have the bright idea of making a class for these object.

```
public class ETLBaseField  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string strFieldPrime;
    private string strField;
    private string strFieldName;

    public ETLBaseField() { }

    public ETLBaseField(string strInputField)
    {
        strFieldName = strInputField;
    }

    public string Field
    {
        get { return strField; }
        set
        {
            if (strField != value)
            {
                strField = value;
                // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
                OnPropertyChanged(strFieldName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Load(string strValue)
    {
        strFieldPrime = strValue;
        strField = strFieldPrime;
    }

    public void Empty()
    {
        Load("");
    }

    public bool isDirty()
    {
        return strFieldPrime != Field;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This class is used by my main class

```
public class RequestProfileObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public ETLBaseField RequestName = new ETLBaseField("RequestName");
     public ETLBaseField InterfaceName = new ETLBaseField("InterfaceName");

    //Plus code that loads the ETLBaseField things and the OnPropertyChanged method
}
```

My xaml code was working, my bindings to the fields were just hunky dory.  Now with my new invention I can't figure out how to bind the RequestName.Field property to the xaml textbox.  The following

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="txtBxInterfaceName" Width="250" 
 Text="{Binding Path=InterfaceName.Field}" />
```

doesn't work.  Was I too smart for my own good in creating the ETLBaseField class?  Should I remove the INPC from RequestProfileObject?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work. Do you see the inital value of InterfaceName.Field? If so, is it not updating the source?

Comment: @Mark: Are you setting the `DataContext` for the class that contains `txtBxInterfaceName`? Can we see that code...

Comment: @cheedep, By not working,I mean nothing displays in my TextBox when I use my ETLBaseField class.

Comment: @jacobaloysious I'm working on getting the necessary subset put together so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: @MarkTJohnson change the OnPropertyChanged in ETLBaseField to be as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mode=TwoWay

```
<TextBox Height="23" Name="txtBxInterfaceName" Width="250" 
     Text="{Binding Path=InterfaceName.Field, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

DataBinding should work as your ETLBaseField is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. In case it doesn't work try setting the TextBox's DataContext explicitly

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding InterfaceName}" Height="23" Name="txtBxInterfaceName" Width="250" 
 Text="{Binding Field}" />
```

You are raising the `OnPropertyChanged` incorrectly!

Not this

```
OnPropertyChanged(strFieldName);
```

Instead do this

```
OnPropertyChanged("Field");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to turn InterfaceName into a Property with Getter. I do not think it will work with Field in as in your example.
So, try this out:

```
private ETLBaseField _interfaceName;
public ETLBaseField InterfaceName
{
  get{return _interfaceName??(_interfaceName = new ETLBaseField("InterfaceName"));
  set{_interfaceName = value;}
}
```

You might not need the Setter if you do not want to use.